# Could not perform immediate configuration on 'libstdc++6' on Nexenta

Tags: package-management, apt, nexenta

My original goal was setup service-network-ssh on Nexenta Illumos. As a result of the command

```
apt-get install service-network-ssh
```

I got the following message

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++6-4.2-dev : Depends: g++-4.2 (= 4.2.3-2nexenta7) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: gcc-4.2-base (= 4.2.3-2nexenta7) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.3-2nexenta7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to do

```
apt-get -f install
```

and received

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apt apt-utils base-passwd binutils ca-certificates coreutils cpp-4.2 debconf
  debconf-i18n debootstrap diff dpkg ed findutils g++-4.2 gawk gcc-4.2
  gcc-4.2-base gettext-base gnupg gpgv grep hostname lib64gcc1 libbz2-1.0
  libcomerr2 libcurl3-gnutls libdb4.6 libgcc1 libgcrypt11 libgnutls13 libgomp1
  libgpg-error0 libgpmg1 libiconv libidn11 libkrb53 libldap-2.4-2
  liblocale-gettext-perl liblzo2-2 libncurses5 libnspr4 libnspr4-0d libnss3
  libnss3-0d libnss3-1d libopencdk10 libreadline5 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules
  libsqlite3-0 libssl0.9.8k libstdc++6 libtasn1-3 libtext-charwidth-perl
  libtext-iconv-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl libtspi1 lzma makedev nexenta-lu
  nexenta-sunw nexenta-zones perl-base readline-common sed sunwbridgeu
  sunwcakr sunwcar sunwckr sunwcnetr sunwcsl sunwcslr sunwcsr sunwcsu
  sunwgrubr sunwkvm sunwlibm sunwpool sunwpoolr sunwsmapi sunwtecla sunwtoo
  sunwtsg sunwtsr sunwtsu sunwzfsr sunwzfsu sunwzoner sunwzoneu ubuntu-keyring
  zlib1g
Suggested packages:
  apt-doc aptitude synaptic gnome-apt wajig dpkg-dev binutils-doc
  gcc-4.2-locales debconf-doc debconf-utils libgnome2-perl libnet-ldap-perl
  libqt-perl libterm-readline-gnu-perl diff-doc mlocate locate slocate
  g++-4.2-multilib gcc-4.2-doc libstdc++6-4.2-dbg gcc-4.2-multilib libgcc1-dbg
  libgomp1-dbg libmudflap0-4.2-dbg libmudflap0-4.2-dev gnupg-doc xloadimage
  rng-tools gnutls-bin krb5-doc krb5-user libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit
  libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal libsasl2-modules-ldap libsasl2-modules-otp
  libsasl2-modules-sql
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt apt-utils base-passwd binutils ca-certificates coreutils cpp-4.2 debconf
  debconf-i18n debootstrap diff dpkg ed findutils g++-4.2 gawk gcc-4.2
  gcc-4.2-base gettext-base gnupg gpgv grep hostname lib64gcc1 libbz2-1.0
  libcomerr2 libcurl3-gnutls libdb4.6 libgcc1 libgcrypt11 libgnutls13 libgomp1
  libgpg-error0 libgpmg1 libiconv libidn11 libkrb53 libldap-2.4-2
  liblocale-gettext-perl liblzo2-2 libncurses5 libnspr4 libnspr4-0d libnss3
  libnss3-0d libnss3-1d libopencdk10 libreadline5 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules
  libsqlite3-0 libssl0.9.8k libstdc++6 libtasn1-3 libtext-charwidth-perl
  libtext-iconv-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl libtspi1 lzma makedev nexenta-lu
  nexenta-sunw nexenta-zones perl-base readline-common sed sunwbridgeu
  sunwcakr sunwcar sunwckr sunwcnetr sunwcsl sunwcslr sunwcsr sunwcsu
  sunwgrubr sunwkvm sunwlibm sunwpool sunwpoolr sunwsmapi sunwtecla sunwtoo
  sunwtsg sunwtsr sunwtsu sunwzfsr sunwzfsu sunwzoner sunwzoneu ubuntu-keyring
  zlib1g
0 upgraded, 92 newly installed, 0 to remove and 416 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/91.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 83.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
E: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'libstdc++6'. Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)
```

Based on the error log of the first command, I tried to remove the package from gсс, to set gсс version 4.2.3 and with the command

```
apt-get --purge remove developer-gcc-44
```

I got

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++6-4.2-dev : Depends: g++-4.2 (= 4.2.3-2nexenta7) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: gcc-4.2-base (= 4.2.3-2nexenta7) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.3-2nexenta7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

What to do - to delete gcc manually (and again to set, and then to set ssh through a repository, but my chief considers, what for the Nexenta operating system  gcc shall be set through the package manager) or to try to set service-network-ssh manually, not through a repository? If the second option preferable, I need links to service-network-ssh installation instructions to Nexenta.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295521/the-steps-to-install-service-network-ssh).

Comment: It's also on [SF](http://serverfault.com/questions/466497/the-steps-to-install-service-network-ssh) now. The other two are closed, we're leaving this one open

Comment: It looks like your package sources are messed up. First, run `apt-get update` then `apt-get -f install`. Then, post the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and of all the files (if any) in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: @Gilles I made, that you advised - didn't help and laid out file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder contents.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to ssh: when you try to install a package, apt first wants to have the database in a clean state, and it isn't. There's a problem with the `libstdc++6` package, which isn't configured.

I'm not directly familiar with the error “Could not perform immediate configuration”. A few things you could try:

- If you have Aptitude, try running it instead of apt-get. In some versions of Debian, aptitude is smarter than apt-get.
- Try `apt-get -o APT::Immediate-Configure=0 -f install`
- Try calling `dpkg` manually to install the troublesome packages: `dpkg --configure -a; dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libstdc++6*`

Comment: What do each of the commands directly `dpkg --configure -a`; `dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libstdc++6*` @Gilles?

Comment: @user1851132 `dpkg --configure -a` configures all packages that have been unpacked but not configured, letting dpkg figure out the order. It might help because here apt-get is having trouble performing the installation steps in the right order. `dpkg -i …` installs the specified package without doing dependency resolution (if a dependency is not met, it will complain, not attempt to resolve it).